# How to get playlistItem using videoId and playlistId out of maxResults range?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

[PlaylistItem](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource) is not retrieved by `videoId` and `playlistId`. This situation occurs when it is not within `maxResults` range.

You would get item has data below query.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=3&playlistId=PLLALQuK1NDrgb03P3lIgK7SrBdYbuh4_5&videoId=H4lRmVy_qYc&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You couldn't get item this time.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=2&playlistId=PLLALQuK1NDrgb03P3lIgK7SrBdYbuh4_5&videoId=H4lRmVy_qYc&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

[Try it here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#try-it)

The only difference thing is just number of `maxResults`. The playlistItem has index 3, so it was't retrieved.

It is fine unless I'll try to get PlaylistItem which is out of maximum number of `maxResults`. But I have to do that. It frustrates me a lot.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: What information from a `PlaylistItem` Resource do you need that is not contained in a `Video` Resource? In other words: Why don't you query the video directly (`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=H4lRmVy_qYc&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`)?

Comment: @paolo I must know whether PlaylistItem is in Playlist or not by only `videoId` and `playlistId`.

Comment: Just take note that in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list), it is already stated there that the required parameters is part and Filters that you need to specify exactly one of these parameter(id and playlistId). Just remember that maxResults is only optional parameter. Just read the description of all the parameters there to know how to use them.

Comment: @KENdi what you said are actually related with my question? The problem is the item is not returned when it has index over 50 (maximum number of `maxResults`) and parameters are `videoId` and `playlistId`. I have to figure it out only using those parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior of the API is actually pretty confusing, I wouldn't expect something like that to happen. After all, the [documentation for the `maxResults` parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#maxResults) states:

> The maxResults parameter specifies the maximum number of items that should be returned in the result set.

Since the video is in the playlist twice, one should assume that requests with the `maxResults` parameter set to either 2 or 3 or any number higher than that would return both items.

**Possible workaround**

I don't really understand why you couldn't just raise the `maxResults` parameter to 50, but this will work:

First, get a list of *all* videos in the playlist (without `videoId` parameter). Set `maxResults` to 50. That way, you have to do one request for every 50 videos in the playlist, but at least this method is reliable. Make sure to regard any `nextPageToken` properties in the response. This is the easiest way to get the items which exceeded `maxResults`.

Optionally, if you do not need further information (like video description, etc.) you can set the `fields` parameter to `items(snippet(position,resourceId/videoId)),nextPageToken`. That way, it will only return the necessary information and reduce the size of the response. Your query could look like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLLALQuK1NDrgb03P3lIgK7SrBdYbuh4_5&fields=items(snippet(position%2CresourceId%2FvideoId))%2CnextPageToken&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

(the `fields` parameter was composed using the fields editor, in the "Try it!" area)

Now that you have the video ids of all items in the playlist, simply check if your id is among them.

Comment: My situation is about the items which exceeded `maxResults`. Getting all of videos is only way to know the video is included playlist?

Comment: I don't know if it's the only way, but it works. As I said, I can't explain this behavior of `maxResults` either and I find it very weird. It may just be a bug in the API, I don't know.